# Hashicorp Vault: Restrict rights given by policy for user allowed to create policies

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I came up with the idea to delegate to a user the right to create a policy. The policy assigned to this user would be:

```
path "sys/policies/acl/user-*"
{
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```

Now as the user can create a policy in the path sys/policies/acl/user-*, such policy could contain any rights to any path in Vault which of course is not what I want to achieve. I would like to restrict this policy creation right to a given path. Is this in any way possible in Vault?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Buy Vault with sentinel support (i believe thats the enterprise version)
2. Create another service that will be talking to vault when it comes to creating policies and then write your own parsers to allow/deny. Its not going to be that bad as the policies hcl config language is translatable to JSON and once you have JSON you can parse the paths and figure out if its a valid policy or not.